# Bounds when computing surface integral of a scalar function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Compute the surface integral of the function $x+z$ over the first octant of the plane $x+y+z=1$

My attempt:

$$ \vec{n} \cdot \vec{k} = \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} = \sqrt{3}$$

Then,

$$ \int_{\partial S} (x+z) dS= \int_{R} (x+z) \frac{dx dy}{\vec{n} \cdot \hat{k}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{R} (x+z)dx dy$$

Now, I plug in equation of plane for $z$ and rearrange the order ( I've ommited the root three outside)

$$ \int_{R} (1-y) dy dx = \int_?^? \int_?^? (1-y) dy dx$$

Now, for the inner integral I am running a double integral in the $x-y$ plane so I put $z=0$ in the equation of plane which gives $x+y=1$ or $ y=1-x$ , and the outer integral is from $ 0 \to 1$,

$$ \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{1-x} (1-y) dy dx  = \int_0^1 [x^2 -1 ] dx = -\frac23$$

But the true answer of the original integral $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ / the new integral should evaluate to one. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z = f(x,y) = 1 - x - y$ is the parametrization of your surface.

$f_x = -1, f_y = - 1, \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} = \sqrt3$

$\int_{S} (x+z) dS = \int_{A} (x+z) \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} \, dA = \sqrt3 \displaystyle  \int_0^1\int_{0}^{1-x} (1-y)  \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

Also note $(x+z)$ is a scalar function and not a vector field so it is not necessary to find $\, \hat{n}\,$ for your integral.

EDIT:

Specifically to your question on the mistake, when you have a vector field your integral translates to

$\displaystyle \iint_R (\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}) \frac{dx \, dy}{\hat{n}.\vec{k}}$

Here your surface is $x + y + z = 1$ which has a normal vector $(1, 1, 1)$.

Unit normal  $\hat{n} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3})$

$\hat{n} \cdot \vec{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

So your integral should be

$\sqrt3 \displaystyle \iint_R (x + z) \, dx \, dy$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the normal to relate the surface area and projection, where exactly is the mistake in my working?

Comment: @Buraian sorry I missed this comment earlier. My point is that as you do not have a vector field, there is no dot product of the vector field with normal vector to the surface so you can simply write $dS = \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} \, dA$. This is projection of your surface on $XY$ plane based on the parametrization. As far as mistake in your working, I will edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Just edited. Please see if this clarifies.

Comment: I still don't get it, can't you switch the order of integration? I can't get where I went wrong still

Comment: First mistake $\hat{n} \cdot \vec{k} \ne \sqrt3$. It is $ = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. Second mistake, $\int_{0}^{1-x} (1-y) dy \ne [x^2 - 1]$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1-x} (1-y) dy = [y - \frac{y^2}{2}]_0^{(1-x)} = \frac{1-x^2}{2}$